# Site with all content on the front page

Tags: menus, pages

I would like to achieve the following:

- all the content is displayed on 1 page (the front page)
- the content is organized in sections
- the content for each section can be edited separately
- each section has a corresponding link in the top menu
- when clicking on a menu item, the browser scrolls down to the corresponding section on the page

And here are my questions:

**Is there a technical term to describe these sort of websites (I've seen a few around)? Can you mention some plugins that would help me achieve this?**

Comment: I think you are talking about a **"Single Page Interface"**. What you are asking isn't really answerable here. It is a big project which I'd count as "work for me for free" making it off-topic per the [faq]. Plugin recommendations are also off-topic per the [faq]. Sorry.

Comment: This is achievable with Gutenberg Blocks if the theme is current say twentytwentyfour.  

First you need to list the type of content...posts, static content and the such.  Or message me.  I have built a page like this using wordpress out the box with same menu link experience youre asking about.

Answer (score -1):

You can just create a HTML page with anchor links:

1- Link pointing to the anchor (Content)

```
<a name="allin"></a>
<div>Content</div>
```

2- Create the anchor (menu).

```
<a href="#allin">Link here</a>
```

Although, i must confess i might not completely understood what you want/need.

But as s_ha_dum said your question is to wide you need to start with some code work.